# How to fix error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that Callback

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, scenebuilder

I am trying to set an editable table, everything was okay until I faced this error while compiling:
**error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that 
    Callback,TableCell> conforms to 
    Callback,TableCell>**

This is the model class

```
    public class Club {
    private int id;
    private String nom;
    private String description;
    private int capacite;
    private String path;
    private  float moyenneLike;
    private String nomcategorie;}
```

and this the controller :

```
   List<CategorieClub> myList = categoriesClubService.selectAll();
   ObservableList<CategorieClub> myObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
   nomCategorie.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nomCategorie"));

   listeCategorie.setEditable(true);
   nomCategorie.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
```

the error occurs in the last line of the controller